# Display unique values in jsp

Tags: jsp

Following code works fine to grab all values and display them, such as Live, Live, Live, Dead etc.

```
<c:forEach var="instState" items="${inst.instanceState}" varStatus="loop">
<c:out value="${instState.userFriendlyString}"/>
<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to avoid displaying duplicate values on the page. Do we have any jsp tag for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such jsp tag. You can write a custom tag if you need. The simplest solution would be to copy the values to a LinkedHashSet and iterate over it

```
<jsp:useBean id="unique" class="java.util.LinkedHashSet" scope="request">
    <%
        unique.add("Live");
        unique.add("Live");
        unique.add("Live");
        unique.add("Dead");
    %>
    </jsp:useBean>

    <c:forEach var="instState" items="${unique}" varStatus="loop">
        <c:out value="${instState}"/>
        <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. 
With above code, it is displaying all values which we add as unique.add(), Such as "Live", "Dead". Thing is I am grabbing results from database and it can be only "Live" or "Dead". So if "Dead" is present in results then only we want to display it.

Thanks